# How do I get a formatted list of methods from a given object?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, and the answers I've found online so far for this have been too complicated to be useful, so I'm looking for an answer in vocabulary and complexity similar to this writing.

I'm using python 2.7 in ipython notebook environment, along with related modules as distributed by anaconda, and I need to learn about the library-specific objects in the course of my daily work. The case I'm using here is a pandas dataframe object but the answer must work for any object of python or of an imported module.

I want to be able to print a list of methods for the given object. Directly from my program, in a concise and readable format. Even if it's just the method names in a list by alphabetical order, that would be great.  A bit more detail would be even better, an ordering based on what it does is fine, but I'd like the output to look like a table, one row per method, and not big blocks of text.  What i've tried is below, and it fails for me because it's unreadable. It puts copies of my data between each line, and it has no formatting.

(I love stackoverflow. I aspire to have enough points someday to upvote all your wonderful answers.)

```
import pandas
import inspect

data_json = """{"0":{"comment":"I won\'t go to school"}, "1":{"note":"Then you must stay in bed"}}"""

data_df = pandas.io.json.read_json(data_json, typ='frame', 
                     dtype=True, convert_axes=True, 
                     convert_dates=True, keep_default_dates=True, 
                     numpy=False, precise_float=False, 
                     date_unit=None)

inspect.getmembers(data_df, inspect.ismethod)
```

Thanks,
- Sharon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of type `str`:

```
name = "Fido"
```

List all its attributes (there are no “methods” in Python) in alphabetical order:

```
for attr in sorted(dir(name)):
    print attr
```

Get more information about the `lower` (function) attribute:

```
print(name.lower.__doc__)
```

In an interactive session, you can also use the more convenient

```
help(name.lower)
```

function.

Comment: There are certainly methods in python.

Comment: @roippi But they are called *function attributes* and not treated any different from any other attribute.

Comment: Except that methods come in *bound* and *unbound* flavors, so the distinction is quite important.  The `inspect` module even has `ismethod` (which the OP is using!) so I don't know how you can believe methods are not a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the correct terminology 5gon12eder. Since you understood what was meant by the word method, I will leave it in the question.  But will try to use the correct word in future (function attributes - who knew?)  thanks again.  -S